# Firebase: how to fix Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'node_modules/protobufjs/google/protobuf/api.proto'

Tags: node.js, firebase, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-firestore

We are making the following query to cloud firestore:

```
 ` var meeting = await db.collection("meetings").where(
    "pin", "==", request.body.Digits).where(
    "status", "==", "in-progress").get()`
```

This works on our local machines, but fails when we deploy to EC2. We have the Firestore client library installed on both, but we webpack it when we deploy.

This error is particularly puzzling because the above snippet is wrapped in a try block, but the following error is thrown on that line without being caught:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'node_modules/protobufjs/google/protobuf/api.proto'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:431:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:333:35)
    at fetch (/home/node/server/app.compiled.js:350251:34)
    at Root.load (/home/node/server/app.compiled.js:350285:13)
    at Root.loadSync (/home/node/server/app.compiled.js:350326:17)
    at Object.loadSync (/home/node/server/app.compiled.js:347406:17)
    at Object../node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/index.js (/home/node/server/app.compiled.js:65075:37)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/node/server/app.compiled.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/server/app.compiled.js:222521:25)
    at Object../node_modules/google-gax/build/src/grpc.js (/home/node/server/app.compiled.js:222775:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/node/server/app.compiled.js:20:30)
    at Object../node_modules/google-gax/build/src/index.js (/home/node/server/app.compiled.js:222819:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/node/server/app.compiled.js:20:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/node/server/app.compiled.js:44631:13)
    at Object../node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_client.js (/home/node/server/app.compiled.js:45987:30)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/node/server/app.compiled.js:20:30)
(node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

We have tried pretty much everything you could think of without actually changing the query- re-doing the package.json and our build scripts, but cannot figure this out. Any help?

Comment: Hace u tríed installing the dependency that is missing?

Comment: Yes, we tried installing protobuf seperately even though it should be installed with Firebase, it still does not work.

Comment: Did you get this working? I am having a similar situation.

Comment: Did not. The workaround was that we moved all firebase calls to backend. Was time consuming but worth it because making calls from browser to firebase is bad style anyways.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the Node.js SDK for Cloud Firestore uses gRPC to communicate, it is built on native code, there are several ways to go around this, but I would recommend dockerizing your application into an image like [this](https://github.com/znly/docker-protobuf)

This problem is kind of similar to [this one](https://thecloudfunction.com/blog/firestore-aws-lambda/) when trying to run the sdk into a AWS lambda.

Hope this points you into a direction